# CSS Underline Menu

Tags: html, css, web

I admit I am a no coder and I need to get this look for my menu:
[image]

I do want to animate it on hover and I want the effect to remain after it's clicked (you can see example of the animation in the CSS code I have attached). So I managed to get the bottom border, but I do want to create some space between the border and text and I also wanna get the top border. For some reason it didn't work for me.

Here's my code so far:

```css
ol, ul {
     list-style: none;
}
 li {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
}
 a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
     color: #61f6ff;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 a::before {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 3px;
     left: 0;
     height: 3px;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #61f6ff;
     transform-origin: right top;
     transform: scale(0, 1);
     transition: color 0.1s,transform 0.2s ease-out;
}
 a:active::before {
     background-color: #61f6ff;
}
 a:hover::before, a:focus::before {
     transform-origin: left top;
     transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Homepage</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Our Services</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Costumers</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign border-top and border-bottom to anchor links and animate them via css3 transitions to achieve fade in like animation. You can also play with padding to achieve more space between border and text. Working code below.

```css
ol,
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0B1B70;
    -webkit-transition: border 200ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: border 200ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: border 200ms ease-out;
    transition: border 200ms ease-out;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 2px;
}

a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #61f6ff;
    border-top: 1px solid #61f6ff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#">Homepage</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#">Our Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#">Costumers</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hey!
Hope you don't mind me asking. First of all, thanks! I almost got it just fine. Here's a link to  my attempt- http://mayabarber.co.il/

The thing is that I want the links not to move on hover. I also wanna make equal space between the two borders and the text. Could you help me with that please?

Comment: Hey! Try adding this to #menuu { border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    border-top: 2px solid transparent;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 50px; } Also you have     margin-top: -5% on the nav container, try making it 0 (<section data-id="9efbb35" ...)

Comment: Hey thanks!  I actually made it -5 because I used a live website builder and I wanted to drag the whole section up. Even though after setting it to 0 it didn't help preventing the jumping text on hover.

Plus- I wanted the border to remain there after the user clicks it. :) How do I do that?

Comment: In order to do that, you would need to transfer all the styles to the relevant a element, because you cant use :focus on divs. You would need to change styles from #menuu to #menuu a. Like this: #menuu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0B1B70;
    -webkit-transition: border 200ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: border 200ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: border 200ms ease-out;
    transition: border 200ms ease-out;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 2px;
}

Comment: #menuu  a:hover,
#menuu  a:focus,
#menuu  a:active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #61f6ff;
    border-top: 1px solid #61f6ff;
}. You can change the styles according to your needs.

Comment: Hi thanks! When I use that it messes with the padding. You can check the above link to see what I mean.

Comment: Since you are using WordPress I would use jQuery to solve the problem: jQuery('#menuu').on('click',function(){
  jQuery('#menuu').removeClass('active');
  jQuery(this).addClass('active');
}); And add css: .active{
     border-bottom: 2px solid transparent; border-top: 2px solid transparent; 
  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173015/discussion-between-gregor-ojstersek-and-rozi).